# Can't send email - Azure MVC site returning 404 from jquery.min.js:2 when attempting to post a form to an ajax request through a controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure

Deploying a web app tonight. Why can't it find /contact, I have tried fullurl.com/contact and other ideas but the file is there the submit button on the page just keeps telling me it's not. Do you see anything wrong with the following that might cause this?

It worked fine before I redeployed with with new smtp credentials. Any azure deployment steps I might have missed that would cause it to not find /contact on a post request?

Error from website:

```
contact 404 xhr jquery.min.js:2 222 B   44 ms

send    @   jquery.min.js:2
ajax    @   jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @   contact:381
```

homecontroller.cs:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("contact")]
        public JsonResult SendContactEmail(string name, string email, string message, string phone, string bot)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                return Json(false);
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bot))
            {
                string subject = String.Format("{0} my contact form", "");
                string messageBody = "<html><body style=\"font-family: Segoe UI, Helvetica, sans-serif;\">";

                var sb = new StringBuilder();

                sb.Append("Name: " + name);
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("Email: " + email);
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("Phone number: " + phone);
                sb.Append("<br />");

                sb.Append("Message: " + message);
                sb.Append("<br /> ");

                messageBody += sb.ToString();

                EmailHelper.SendEmail(new EmailInfo
                {
                    Body = messageBody,
                    FromName = "my name",
                    Subject = subject,
                    ToAddresses = new StringCollection { "myemail@email.com" }
                }, "");
            }

            return Json(true);
        }



        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }

    public class EmailInfo
    {
        public string FromName { get; set; }

        public StringCollection ToAddresses { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmailHelper
    {
        public static bool SendEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo, string attachmentPath)
        {
            //TODO: From Email information -- Needs to be your email account username and password
            string smtpMailServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
            string smtpUserName = "account";
            string smtpPassword = "key";
            int smtpPort = 587;

            var oMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            var fromMailAddress = new MailAddress(smtpUserName, "my addy");
            oMailMessage.From = fromMailAddress;
            oMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            oMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            oMailMessage.Subject = emailInfo.Subject;
            oMailMessage.Body = emailInfo.Body;

            foreach (string to in emailInfo.ToAddresses)
            {
                oMailMessage.To.Add(to);
            }

            var oSmtpClient = new SmtpClient(smtpMailServer, smtpPort);
            oSmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUserName, smtpPassword);
            oSmtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

            try
            {
                oSmtpClient.Send(oMailMessage);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ajax script appearing on /contact page:

```
    document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/contact',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (res) {
                $(window).scrollTop(350);
                if (res) {
                    $(".contact-form").html("<h3 style='color: #c2ae79; text-align: center' class='wow fadeInUp' data-wow-duration='1s'>Thank you for contacting us! We will be in touch shortly.</p>");
                } else {
                    $(".contact-form").prepend("<h3 style='color: red; text-align: center'>Please check all required fields.</p>");
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account for sendgrid always has to be 'apikey'

```
        //TODO: From Email information -- Needs to be your email account username and password
        string smtpMailServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net";
        string smtpUserName = "account";
        string smtpPassword = "key";
        int smtpPort = 587;
```

So when you cast that into the email constructor:

```
var fromMailAddress = new MailAddress(smtpUserName, "my addy");
```

It throws an error, and if you do it inside of a compiled binary on a live website it throws a 404.

You can use breakpoints and localhost inside of the controller file in order to see a more accurate error message.

Changing the email constructor to accept an actual email fixes this issue.